# Anyone know a good random number generator

Tags: c#, random

I'm trying to create a procedural cave generator and so far I have the code for generating a completely random map:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;

namespace CelularAutomata
{
    class Program
    {
        static int width=512, height=512;
        Boolean[,] cellmap = new Boolean[width, height];
        static float chanceToStartAlive = 0.45f;

        public static Boolean[,] initialiseMap()
        {
            Boolean[,] map = new Boolean[width, height];

            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                Random rng = new Random();
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {
                    doube random = rng.NextDouble();
                    if (random < chanceToStartAlive)
                    {
                        map[x,y] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return map;
        }

        public static Bitmap createImage(Boolean[,] map)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(512, 512);

            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    if (map[x, y])
                    {
                        bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255));
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0));
                    }
                 }
                Console.Write('\n');
            }
            return bmp;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Boolean[,] map = initialiseMap();
            Bitmap bmp = createImage(map);
            bmp.Save("C:\\Users\\radu\\Documents\\Sync\\Licenta\\chamber.png");
        }
    }
}
```

The image I'm trying to obtain is something like this, except in black and white:

[image: desired image]

What I'm getting is this:

[image: generated image]

I believe it's because of the random number generator I'm using (i.e. just `Random().NextDouble()`).
Anyone know a better RNG?

Comment: You're creating a new RNG for each column. Create just one for your whole program. The reason for the artifact on the right third of your image is that you are constructing `Random` with no seed, which implicitly uses `Environment.TickCount` as a seed, which happened to have changed at that column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Random rng = new Random();` inside the for loop, create a single instance above, and use the same instance in each loop. This is because multiple `Random` instances created in quick succession will have the same seed and therefore generate the same sequence of pseudorandom numbers.

For example:

```
class Program
{
    Random rng = new Random();
    ...
    public static Boolean[,] initialiseMap()
    {
        Boolean[,] map = new Boolean[width, height];

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                double random = rng.NextDouble();
                if (random < chanceToStartAlive)
                {
                    map[x,y] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: yeah, that solved it, thanks; i could've sworn i put it ouside the for from the start.